# How to use value of STRING bean in html:hidden tag?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I used `request.addAttribute("myStrBean", "someStr");` now I want to use it in an  tag e.g. `<html:hidden name="myStrBean"/>`. Obviously that isn't working, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but
if you want to get value from request you can use scriplet i.e.

```
<c:set var="myStrBean" value='<%=request.getAttribute("myStrBean")%>'/>
```

But to set data to struts html you should use the ActionForm
example

```
<html:hidden name="MyActionForm" property="myStrBean" />
```

Edit thanks to dave : 
Using EL

```
<c:set var="myStrBean" value="${myStrBean}" />
```

Comment: The first example would be more appropriate using JSP EL instead of a scriptlet, if it's a request attribute.

Comment: We have an ActionForm that contains a complex object. This complex object has a toString. All I want to do is manually do request.addAttribute("complexObject", complexObj.toString()); then write it out to the .jsp page as a hidden field. The reason for doing this is so the value will be retained across requests.

Comment: well in that case, using normal hidden should be enough... <input type="hidden" name="myStrBean" value="${myStrBean}" />